# google mock expect_call to retire another expectation

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have two mocks. Only one of them should be called for a single run and I would like to use the expectations to figure out if the `execute()` function is successful without knowing from the given preconditions.
How can this be achieved?

```
Mock1 successMock;
Mock2 failMock;

EXPECT_CALL(successMock, performOnSuccess()).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(failMock, performOnFail()).Times(0);
execute(successMock, failMock);
```

Either above should be valid or below expectations but only one of them.

```
EXPECT_CALL(successMock, performOnSuccess()).Times(0);
EXPECT_CALL(failMock, performOnFail()).Times(1);
```

Comment: I cannot understand your case well. Can you elaborate a little more? Are these expectations from two different test cases?
For what I'm understanding, you are not sure what is going to happen when you call `execute`, and I don't think this is the use case for mocks ...

Comment: I would like to have both expectation sets valid in the same test case but exclusively, as you say I'm not sure what the outcome of execute is but I know only one of the mocks should be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *expect* is that *one* (and only one) of the collaborators has been called.

One viable solution (as presented in [other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099522/verify-that-either-one-method-or-the-other-was-invoked-in-a-unit-test)) is to make these mocks to **increment a shared counter** in the test scope.

You can achieve this with GoogleMock by [defining actions](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#setting-default-actions). It would be something like this:

```
SuccessMock successMock;
FailMock failMock;

int callCounter = 0;


ON_CALL(successMock, performOnSuccess())
  .WillByDefault(InvokeWithoutArgs([&]()
                 {
                     callCounter++;
                 });

ON_CALL(failMock, performOnFailure())
  .WillByDefault(InvokeWithoutArgs([&]()
                 {
                     callsCounter++;
                 });


execute(successMock, failMock);

ASSERT_THAT(callsCounter, Eq(1));
```

Having said this, this test has some randomness in it that I don't really like. You should be end up having one test expecting failure and another one expecting success.

I wrote an simplified [gist](https://gist.github.com/jsrois/1974a5bf7c97dfdaa70ef4ecacca43fc) for this.